# ATM withdrawing cash in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get 2х 5000 1х 500 and 2x 200 using for in Loop in Python?

```
def get_cash(sum):
    bancnotes = [5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]
    active = True
    while active:
        for bancnote in bancnotes:
            if (sum % bancnote) >= 0 and sum > 0 and sum >= bancnote:
                print(f'Выдано: {bancnote}')
                sum -= bancnote
            else:
                active = False
get_cash(12900)
```

Comment: what is your code supposed to achieve exactly? your wording and the code provided dont make much sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you might need more than one of a given note, you need a loop *inside* the `for bancnote` loop that continues counting out notes in that denomination until it's time to move on to a smaller one.

(Note: `sum` is a builtin function in Python; it's considered poor practice to use builtin function names as variable names because it hides the function.)

```
def get_cash(total):
    bancnotes = [5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]
    for bancnote in bancnotes:
        while total >= bancnote:
            total -= bancnote
            print(f'Выдано: {bancnote}')
    if total:
        print(f"Remainder: {total}")


get_cash(12900)
```

```
Выдано: 5000
Выдано: 5000
Выдано: 2000
Выдано: 500
Выдано: 200
Выдано: 200
```

Comment: but this breaks for get_cash(101) even though there's a valid solution

Comment: I don't think that's part of the assignment.  :)

Comment: its ok i wont be lazy ill get you a full answer

Answer (score -1):

im assuming what you want is the **minimum** number of bank notes that would add up to a given sum (otherwise you could return all 2's with one 5 if it's an odd number). here's a recursive function that can solve this:

```
def min_notes(x):
    if x in [1,3]:
        print("can't do cash for 1 or 3")
        return []
    for n in notes:
         if x == n:
             return [n]
         if x > n and x - n not in [1,3]:
             return min_notes(x - n) + [n]
    return [2] * (x//2)
```

as you might know 1 and 3 are the only numbers that cannot be created with the notes so the code does a avoids them (and makes sure to not reach them recursively). i should note that depending on the bank notes this code might need to be more complex